# Dialog Box is not close after i update the button in dialogbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to close the dialog box automatically after i update the button in dialogbox, but it will not close automatically, is there any proper solution to resolve this issue? this is my code.

```
<script>
jQuery(function () {
    var jQuerydialog = jQuery("#view_dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Schedule',
        height: 200,
        width: 350,
        resizable: true,
        modal: true,
    });
    jQuery(".view_dialog").click(function () {
        jQuerydialog.load(jQuery(this).attr('href'),

        function () {
            jQuerydialog.dialog('open');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I used but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change of code will work. :)

```
 function dialogOpen(param){

        //Getting Html For View
     var result = jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: FULL_BASE_URL+"url"+param,
            async: false
          });
     createDialogBoxById('view_dialog','title','350','200',result.responseText);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('#view_dialog').dialog('close');` should work fine.

Comment: thanks patersonjs, but kindly tell me where i can add this line in my code?